# How to trigger change event to get new radius, latitude and longitude using agm-circle angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working on application in which i am using map which get the user current location user can change location as well. I am using agm-map with agm-circle. When user change radius or dragged the the circle i want to trigger an event. Here is my code. I am using angular 4

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-circle
    [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
    [circleDraggable]="true"
    [editable]="true"
    [fillColor]="circleColor"
    [radius]="locationRadius">
</agm-circle>
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger event like by the following attribute.

```
   <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
        <agm-circle
        [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
        [circleDraggable]="true"
        [editable]="true"
        [fillColor]="circleColor"
        (centerChange)="centerChange($event)"
        [radius]="locationRadius"
    >
    </agm-circle>
    </agm-map>
```

On component end your method

```
 centerChange($event){
    console.log($event);
  }
```

Hope this solve your problem

Reference link you have to study for more events

[agm-circle](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmcircle#radiusChange)

Comment: Thanks alot it works and also for the link i am going to study it